# Minimal normal subgroups in a non-torsion group

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples

Is there a group $G$ with an element with infinite order such that every non-trivial $N \unlhd G$ contains a minimal (non-trivial) normal subgroup of $G$?

Comment: It seems that an infinite (non-torsion) simple group would do, but somehow that seems not very interesting.

Comment: yes, seems so‌. The product of 2 such groups may be a better example. thnx.

Comment: Things like $\operatorname{SL}_n(K)$ for $K$ a field of characteristic $0$ work too (simple algebraic groups that are not simple as abstract groups). They have DCC (and ACC) on normal subgroups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a field $F$. Consider the semidirect product $G$ of the additive group $A$ of $F$ by the multiplicative group $M = F^{\star}$, the latter acting on the former by multiplication.

Then $A$ is the unique minimal normal subgroup of $G$. And if the characteristic of $F$ is zero, then $G$ has elements of infinite order.

Comment: *$A$ is the unique minimal normal subgroup of $G$* is interesting!